# Struts2 result type="redirectAction" doesn't redirect

Tags: java, ajax, struts2

I have a program where the following code (not written by myself) works as intented:

.JSP code:

```
<input type="submit" value="add sample" name="action:dataAddSample" id="buttonAddSample"/>
```

STRUTS.XML code:

```
<action name="dataAddSample" class="com.invenso.xperido.controller.DataCRUD" method="addSample">
    <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">dataform</param>
        <param name="id">${data.id}</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

After the actionmethod `addSample`  returns "success", the action `dataform` is performed, and this action redirects the user to the following url (that uses parameter id):

```
http://localhost:8080/Test/data/dataform.action?id=11476
```

I copied this code in the same package & namespace to achieve a similar workflow, only with different action method (delete instead of add):

```
<action name="dataDeleteSample" class="com.invenso.xperido.controller.DataCRUD" method="deleteSample">
    <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">dataform</param>
        <param name="id">${data.id}</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

I changed the way the action is invoked by using ajax instead of directly linking the input button to the action:

JAVASCRIPT/AJAX code:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "<s:property value='urlDeleteSample'/>",
data: { sampleDBName: sampleName, sampleDBQueryName: queryName },
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){ ......
```

The URL is exactly the link to the action so that works. With the use of debug messages I can confirm the action `dataDeleteSample` triggers, and the method `deleteSample` is invoked. But for some reason the user is not redirected to the url like above. I even removed all business logic in the method `deleteSample` and just let it return Action.SUCCES, but still the result does not seem to trigger the dataform action and redirect the user.

What could cause this? Is it the fact I used AJAX? I'm not familiar enough with struts to know why the first code works, but mine doesn't. Any insights on how the struts framework handles this scenario is welcome.

Comment: There is no `data.id` in your ajax call.

Comment: That is indeed the case! I changed the AJAX data to be: 
data: { sampleDBName: sampleName, sampleDBQueryName: queryName, dataID = id }
But now I don't know what to type in struts.xml to acces this data? <param name="id">${dataID}</param> doesn't work, but <param name="id">15745</param> (that's the literal string...) does work.

Comment: Why not to use same name `data.id`?

Comment: data is the name of a field in my java class where the action methods also resides. On a "data" object, i can do getId(); and setId(); So data.id is the struts way of getting the id. But for some reason, when i use ajax, $(data.id) doesn't give me 15745 but empty string. However, I sysout data.getId() and it is NOT empty, it is in fact 15745.

Answer (score 0):

You won't notice the redirect because you are calling it with AJAX, which means that the DATA you get must be appended into the DOM in order to see the result. In the success event handler you must do that. It might be failing there, debug it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace with type="chain"

```
<action name="remove" class="com.action.firstAction" method="remove">
     <result name="success" type="chain">secondaction</result>
</action>
<action name="second action" class="com.action.secondAction" method="result">
    <result name="success">result.jsp</result>
</action>
```